# Matlab- Max number of digits after decimal point

Tags: matlab, format, double, decimal, printf

I would like to have **max** 3 digits after decimal point when it is necessary.`Sprintf` and `format bank` do not give me what I need. This numbers are going to be in a text box on a figure.

Basically what I tried :

`tt=2.4242
sprintf('%.3f', tt)
tt=2.424`

that's good for the numbers that have 3 or more digits after decimal point but what if I have no digit ( For the math guys : I mean 0 after decimal point) or 1 digit, it doesn't look that good. For example:

```
tt= 0 
sprintf('%.3f', tt)
tt=0.000
```

Is there a function for that or do I have to do that with `if` or `for`?

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Try `g` specifier instead of `f`: `sprintf('%.4g', tt)` ... [How to have sprintf to ignore trailing zeros](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24672741/684399)

Comment: @CitizenInsane Yeah that worked! You can enter it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `sprintf('%.3f', tt)`, use [`regexprep`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) to

- remove **trailing zeros**, if any;
- remove also the **decimal point** if all digits after it are zero.

That is:

```
regexprep(sprintf('%.3f', tt), '(\.*0+)$', '')
```

Examples:

```
>> tt = 4.1; regexprep(sprintf('%.3f', tt), '(\.*0+)$', '')
ans =
4.1

>> tt = 4; regexprep(sprintf('%.3f', tt), '(\.*0+)$', '')
ans =
4
```

Comment: Absolutely! This works even for 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try `g` format specifier instead of `f`:

```
sprintf('%.4g', tt)
```

See also: [How to have sprintf to ignore trailing zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24672741/684399) (Give @RTL is due, I asked the same question a few days ago, this is why I know the answer).

Comment: This doesn't work in general. Example: `sprintf('%.4g', 56.1234)`

Comment: @CitizenInsane how can I make it work for 0 as well ? If the number is 0.5556, this doesn't do anything. Any idea?

Comment: @LuisMendo Indeed! Now somehow confused how to clearly read %[flags][width][**.precision**][length]specifier. For g and G specifiers: This is the **maximum number of significant digits** to be printed. Anyway `regexprep(sprintf(...))` => simpler & general => perfect !